# Why can't SABnzbd assign a port

Tags: 14.04, server

I'm attempting to run SAB on a new Ubuntu 14.04 box. But it won't start, always failing with 'error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address' no matter the user or port I start with. Even root gets denied. I know that the typical answer is that the port is taken but it doesn't appear to be so:

```
    hofo@pellmell:~$ sudo netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6947/smbd       
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34446           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1942/Plex Plug-in [
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31419/apache2   
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32400           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1652/Plex Media Ser
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10246/Xvnc4     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32469           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2449/Plex DLNA Serv
    tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2100/dnsmasq    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1631/sshd       
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27115/cupsd     
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:62202           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2449/Plex DLNA Serv
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6947/smbd       
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50176           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2828/Plex Plug-in [
    tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      6947/smbd       
    tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN      10246/Xvnc4     
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1631/sshd       
    tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      6947/smbd
```

Any ideas what I should look at next?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with IP 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 or `localhost`. (Same same but different...)

```
sudo sabnzbdplus --server 127.0.0.1:8745
```